# javascript deselect checkbox when deselecting another checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I would like to have the possibility with javascript to deselect checkbox "demo2" when I deselect checkbox "demo1".
only deselect

```
<input type="checkbox" name="demo1" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="demo2" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
```

Comment: What is "demo1"?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your work so far so that we can help you modify it. Basically you can accomplish this with a change listener on demo1 and a check to see its status via .checked

Comment: Can you not use radio buttons? They are intented for this type of use, with only one option selected at a time. It will work OOTB

Comment: Use [radio buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp), as @jeroen kindly suggested. Don't try to reinvent the way basic form controls are meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I gues you just want to have "[radio](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)" like behaviour.
You can see below how it can be done with pure JS.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
function switcher(obj) {
   if(obj.checked == true) {
      document.getElementsByName('demo2')[0].checked = false;
      document.getElementsByName('demo1')[0].checked = false;
      obj.checked= true
   }
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="demo1" value="Bike" onclick="switcher(this)">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="demo2" value="Car" onclick="switcher(this)">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not what I wanted, I apologize for having explained me wrong.  demo1 and demo 2 can also be selected both, but demo2 can only be selected if demo1 is selected, and when demo1 is de-selected also demo2 must be deselected

Comment: Ok, this is still not far off. You can create another method and apply the checks as wanted.